# How do I find out with Ubuntu whether my computer has a SATA or PATA hard drive interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a tool for Ubuntu that will detect whether I have a SATA or a PATA hard drive interface, even if there's no hard drive inserted?

Comment: Drive bays usually don't have an interface. Are you talking about a backplane?

Comment: I edited it up to make a little more sense (hopefully). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo lshw -C storage
```

should display all storage controllers you have

Answer (score 2):

`lspci` will list what PCI/AGP/PCI Express devices your system has. One of them is bound to be a storage controller.

Answer (score 1):

`mount` displays what block device stores the filesystem.

PATA harddisks end up in /dev/hd*
SATA harddisks end up in /dev/sd*

If you do something fancy with RAID it might be different.

Comment: PATA hasn't been `hdX` since the introduction of libata.